# Custom URL Schemes for multiple projects

Tags: ios, objective-c, info.plist

I have a project where I have a few apps which share a single Info.plist file. I have been trying to set a custom URL scheme for them individually. I have been looking at variable names like `${SOME_NAME}`. I would like to know how I can create a variable named `URL_SCHEME`, which I can access in my Info.plist file like so `${URL_SCHEME}`, thus avoiding the need to create individual ones for each app. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-process Info.plist files with values from a header file.

1. Create a header file with appropriate `#define` statements.
2. In your app's build settings, set `Preprocess Info.plist File` to `YES`.
3. In your app's build settings, set `Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File` to the path to the header file you created in #1.